# Remove duplicate records in first column but dont modify the rest of columns

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to remove the duplicate records in column 1, keeping the first instance. But keeping the rest of columns untouched .

input

```
444444              21-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117, 
444444              116,118,124-125,120,122-123,126,132.                       
444444              25-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117, 
444444              110,118,124-125,120,122-123,126,132.                       
111111              21-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117, 
111111              116,118,124-125,120,122.                                   
111111              21-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117, 
232323              20-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117, 
232323              116,118,124-125,120,122-123,126,132.
```

output

```
444444              21-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117, 
                    116,118,124-125,120,122-123,126,132.                       
                    25-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117, 
                    110,118,124-125,120,122-123,126,132.                       
111111              21-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117, 
                    116,118,124-125,120,122.                                   
                    21-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117, 
232323              20-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117, 
                    116,118,124-125,120,122-123,126,132.
```

i tried

```
 awk '!NF {print;next}; !($1 in a) {a[$1];print}' file
```

Also, tried split the file in two parts :

```
file 1: first column and remove the duplicates and keep first > output1
file 2: Second Column 
paste output1 file2 > file-output.
```

Is there the option to do in simple awk line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `awk` may work for you:

```
awk 'seen[$1]++{$1="\t\t"} 1' file
```

```
444444   21-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117,
         116,118,124-125,120,122-123,126,132.
111111   21-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117,
         116,118,124-125,120,122.
232323   21-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117,
         116,118,124-125,120,122-123,126,132.
```

Comment: anubhava, great, it works like this to keep same format in 2 column awk 'seen[$1]++{$1="                   "} 1' file.

Comment: Yes that would work fine as well. I added `\t\t` to get some extra spacing in first column

Answer (score 1):

If your Input_file is sorted by first column like you showed then following may help you on same.

```
awk 'prev==$1{$1="                   "} 1; {prev=$1}'   Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In case your Input_file is not sorted then following may help you on same.

```
 awk '++a[$1]>1{$1="                   "} 1'   Input_file
```

Comment: RavinderSingh13, great, 2nd option works better in my case, tks

Answer (score 1):

To keep format of lines

You can try

```
awk '$1!=prev{prev=new=$1;gsub("."," ",new);print;next}{sub($1,new)}1' input
```

if $1 contains regexp metachars

```
awk '
  $1!=prev {
    prev=new=$1
    gsub("."," ",new)
    print
    next }
  { i=split($1,a,//)
    b=""
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
    b=b "[" a[j] "]"
    sub(b,new) }
1' input
```

Comment: @EdMorton give a example of fail $1 so i can see what I can do.

Comment: Try it with $1 `.*`.

Comment: @EdMorton I update the answer for .*, you have an other ?

Comment: What any awk will do for field splitting given a null string as the regexp to split on is undefined behavior by POSIX so YMMV with `split($i,a,//)` - some awks will do what you want, some definitely won't. The approach of enclosing each char in `[]` fails when the char is `^` anyway though since `^` becomes the negation char when placed at the front of a bracket expression - you have to special-case that so it becomes `\^` while every other char X becomes `[X]`. As you can tell by all the problems, it's just the wrong approach - change `sub($1,new)` to `sub(/[^[:space:]]+/,new)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that modifies $1 **does** modify the record. The way to **really** do what you asked for is:

```
$ awk 'seen[$1]++{rep=$1; gsub(/./," ",rep); sub(/[^[:space:]]+/,rep)} 1' file
444444              21-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117,
                    116,118,124-125,120,122-123,126,132.
                    25-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117,
                    110,118,124-125,120,122-123,126,132.
111111              21-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117,
                    116,118,124-125,120,122.
                    21-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117,
232323              20-84,87,85-86,88-106,108,111,109,112,110,113,115,114,117,
                    116,118,124-125,120,122-123,126,132.
```

The above **only** removes the duplicate $1 values and leaves everything else, including white space within and between fields, exactly as-is.

Comment: Ed, it works only if the duplicate lines in column 2 does not exceed more  than 2 times, if it is > 2 the code does not work. I have modified the input file with better example.

Comment: If there is another serie of 444444 at the end , $2 is print with 232323.

Comment: Right but since the OP accepted an answer based on using a seen[] array, that must be adequate for this problem and his data must look just like his posted example where later repetitions of the same key value don't occur.